# Sed - conditional branching within an address range

Tags: parsing, loops, sed, branch, label

I needed to format a bulk entry file from some raw text data. I was able to achieve the bulk of my solution using `Sed`, which was/is preferred, but not absolutely required (I'd just like to stick to this one tool). The problem became clear when I got branch crazy trying to parse through [a much larger amount of] the following input:

```
---- Start Product ----
PartNumber>> 123457
Size04_Req>> 2 
Size02_Req>> 1 
PartColor>> Natural
PartDescription>> Guys Tee 
---- End Product ----
---- Start Product ----
PartNumber>> TPIOO9205
Size05_Req>> 1 
PartColor>> Natural
PartDescription>> Black Hoodie


---- End Product ----


###...with the objective of achieving the following output:


---- Start Product ---
PartNumber>> 123457
Size01_Req>> 0 
Size03_Req>> 0 
Size05_Req>> 0 
Size06_Req>> 0
Size04_Req>> 2 
Size02_Req>> 1 
PartColor>> Natural
PartDescription>> Guys Tee
---- End Product ----
---- Start Product ----
PartNumber>> TPIOO9205
Size01_Req>> 0 
Size02_Req>> 0 
Size03_Req>> 0 
Size04_Req>> 0 
Size06_Req>> 0
Size05_Req>> 1 
PartColor>> Natural
PartDescription>> Black Hoodie
---- End Product ----
```

I do believe this is as simple as working within the address range **/----\ Start\ Product\ ----/,/----\ End\ Product\ ----/** and doing some elegant branch and :label work, but my inclination, obviously, is to jump on Awk or something for this logic - because I'm going nuts -- and it would be easier, perhaps, with another tool to achieve this. However, sticking to my original desire to stay with Sed, and because I like to learn me a new Sed trick any day, how might this be done? Notice that the logic is to insert **SizeXX_Req>> 0**  for the sizes 01-06 that are not accounted for, and the order is not important, which is why I was thinking Sed could get even this last little part done semi-sanely. There will always be at least one **SizeXX_Req** line in between each Start/End Product section. Any Sed(i) Masters make quick work of this? Am I just geeking out from the boatload of regular expressions I've been writing lately and missing an easy fix?
Go ahead. Show me in another rando language without even explaining how (or why) you did, I'm down with that, too. Thanks  in advance, peeps.

Comment: Fixing the missing bits is, I think, beyond `sed` (or, at any rate, beyond sane `sed` or only mildly insane `sed`).  You would do better with a full programming language — `awk`, `perl`, `python`, ...

Comment: complicated logics are always well presented in other tools:awk or even start from scratch using scripting language. I would not preder sed underthis situation.

Comment: So it is indeed beyond what one could accomplish in Sed? It seemed so to me, but I thought perhaps I was just reaching the boundaries of my personal skill with Sed rather than Sed itself. Only because :labels and branches seem, like, well, they can get 'deep', heh, ya know? [f]awk it, I will. But I'd still be tickled with some Sed trickery >:-) Anyone wanna drop the awk while I go shift gears? feel free!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this using just sed seems impossible to me since you need a counter and some sort of back reference. Perhaps I'm wrong, anyway, using Perl:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my (%sizes, %part);
while(<>) {
  if (/^---- End Product ----/) {
    print "---- Start Product ----\n";
    print "PartNumber>> $part{Number}\n";
    for my $size (map { sprintf "%02d", $_ } 1..6) {
      if (not defined $sizes{$size}) {
        print "<b>Size${size}_Req>> 0</b>\n";
      }   
    }   
    for my $size (keys %sizes) {
      print "Size${size}_Req>> $sizes{$size}\n";
    }   
    print "Part$_>> $part{$_}\n" for ("Color", "Description");
    print "---- End Product ----\n";
    %sizes = (); 
    %part  = (); 
  }
  $sizes{$1} = $2 if (/^Size(\d+)_Req>>\s*(\d+)/);
  $part{$1} = $2 if (/^Part(\w+)>> (.*)/);
}
```

**Use**

```
perl script.pl input
```

**Output**

```
---- Start Product ----
PartNumber>> 123457
<b>Size01_Req>> 0</b>
<b>Size03_Req>> 0</b>
<b>Size05_Req>> 0</b>
<b>Size06_Req>> 0</b>
Size04_Req>> 2
Size02_Req>> 1
PartColor>> Natural
PartDescription>> Guys Tee 
---- End Product ----
---- Start Product ----
PartNumber>> TPIOO9205
<b>Size01_Req>> 0</b>
<b>Size02_Req>> 0</b>
<b>Size03_Req>> 0</b>
<b>Size04_Req>> 0</b>
<b>Size06_Req>> 0</b>
Size05_Req>> 1
PartColor>> Natural
PartDescription>> Black Hoodie
---- End Product ----
```

Comment: Thanks @perreal - this works like a charm. If no Sedophiles chime in, it's great to have a solution in place. But I am going to leave it unanswered to see if the Sed comes through! Cheers!